# Converting a column of type 'list' to multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with one column which is a list, like so:

```
>head(movies$genre_list)
[[1]]
[1] "drama"   "action"  "romance"
[[2]]
[1] "crime" "drama"
[[3]]
[1] "crime"   "drama"   "mystery"
[[4]]
[1] "thriller" "indie"  
[[5]]
[1] "thriller"
[[6]]
[1] "drama"  "family"
```

I want to convert this one column to multiple columns, one for each unique element across the lists (in this case, genres), and have them as binary columns. I'm looking for an elegant solution, which doesn't involve first finding out how many genres are there, and then creating a column for each, and then checking each list element to then populate the genre columns. I tried unlist, but it doesn't work with a vector of lists in the way I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Does each list item always have unique genres? In other words, can a record be "drama, action, romance, action"?

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few approaches:

```
movies <- data.frame(genre_list = I(list(
   c("drama",   "action",  "romance"),
   c("crime", "drama"),
   c("crime",   "drama",   "mystery"),
   c("thriller", "indie"),  
   c("thriller"),
   c("drama",  "family"))))
```

---

## Update, years later....

You can use the `mtabulate` function from "qdapTools" or the unexported `charMat` function from my "splitstackshape" package.

Syntax would be:

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(movies$genre_list)
#   action crime drama family indie mystery romance thriller
# 1      1     0     1      0     0       0       1        0
# 2      0     1     1      0     0       0       0        0
# 3      0     1     1      0     0       1       0        0
# 4      0     0     0      0     1       0       0        1
# 5      0     0     0      0     0       0       0        1
# 6      0     0     1      1     0       0       0        0
```

or

```
splitstackshape:::charMat(movies$genre_list, fill = 0)
#      action crime drama family indie mystery romance thriller
# [1,]      1     0     1      0     0       0       1        0
# [2,]      0     1     1      0     0       0       0        0
# [3,]      0     1     1      0     0       1       0        0
# [4,]      0     0     0      0     1       0       0        1
# [5,]      0     0     0      0     0       0       0        1
# [6,]      0     0     1      1     0       0       0        0
```

## Update: A couple of more direct approaches

**Improved option 1**: Use `table` somewhat directly:

```
table(rep(1:nrow(movies), sapply(movies$genre_list, length)), 
      unlist(movies$genre_list, use.names=FALSE))
```

**Improved option 2**: Use a `for` loop.

```
x <- unique(unlist(movies$genre_list, use.names=FALSE))
m <- matrix(0, ncol = length(x), nrow = nrow(movies), dimnames = list(NULL, x))
for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
  m[i, movies$genre_list[[i]]] <- 1
}
m
```

---

***Below is the OLD answer***

Convert the list to a list of `table`s (in turn converted to `data.frame`s):

```
tables <- lapply(seq_along(movies$genre_list), function(x) {
  temp <- as.data.frame.table(table(movies$genre_list[[x]]))
  names(temp) <- c("Genre", paste("Record", x, sep = "_"))
  temp
})
```

Use `Reduce` to `merge` the resulting list. If I understand your end goal correctly, this results in the transposed form of the result you are interested in.

```
merged_tables <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), tables)
merged_tables
#      Genre Record_1 Record_2 Record_3 Record_4 Record_5 Record_6
# 1   action        1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 2    drama        1        1        1       NA       NA        1
# 3  romance        1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
# 4    crime       NA        1        1       NA       NA       NA
# 5  mystery       NA       NA        1       NA       NA       NA
# 6    indie       NA       NA       NA        1       NA       NA
# 7 thriller       NA       NA       NA        1        1       NA
# 8   family       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        1
```

Transposing and converting `NA` to `0` is pretty straightforward. Just drop the first column and re-use it as the column `names` for the new `data.frame`

```
movie_genres <- setNames(data.frame(t(merged_tables[-1])), merged_tables[[1]])
movie_genres[is.na(movie_genres)] <- 0
movie_genres
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the same input as in the other replies here are some alternatives:

1) **factor/table/rbind**

```
> levs <- levels(factor(unlist(movies[[1]])))
> as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(movies[[1]], factor, levs), table)))
  action crime drama family indie mystery romance thriller
1      1     0     1      0     0       0       1        0
2      0     1     1      0     0       0       0        0
3      0     1     1      0     0       1       0        0
4      0     0     0      0     1       0       0        1
5      0     0     0      0     0       0       0        1
6      0     0     1      1     0       0       0        0
```

2) **make.groups/xtabs**

```
> library(lattice)
> m <- do.call(make.groups, movies[[1]])
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~ which + data, m))
                                action crime drama family indie mystery romance thriller
c("drama", "action", "romance")      1     0     1      0     0       0       1        0
c("crime", "drama")                  0     1     1      0     0       0       0        0
c("crime", "drama", "mystery")       0     1     1      0     0       1       0        0
c("thriller", "indie")               0     0     0      0     1       0       0        1
thriller                             0     0     0      0     0       0       0        1
c("drama", "family")                 0     0     1      1     0       0       0        0
```

2a) **make.groups/dcast** This one is a variation on alternative 2 using `dcast` from reshape2 in place of `as.data.frame.matrix` and `xtabs`.  Melted data frame `m` is from alternative 2.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(m, which ~ data, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "which")
```

UPDATE: Added alternative 2.

UPDATE 2: Added alternative 2a.

Comment: Thanks! I like solution 1 the most! I'm just not used to `lattice` enough to grok solution 2.

Comment: @New, Have split #2 into two lines so the melted data frame `m` can be inspected.  That might improve understandability.