# Turn column with factors in a list into a model matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, model.matrix

So I have a data.frame that I would like to turn into a model.matrix.  This is all in R

Here is an example of what I have:

```
   col1
1 "factor1","factor2"
2 "factor1"
3 "factor3"
4 "factor1","factor2"
```

I would like to create the following output:

```
   factor1 factor2 factor3
1    1       1       0
2    1       0       0
3    0       0       1
4    1       1       0
```

I would appreciate any advice! I have been using sparse.model.matrix to no avail as it creates unique factor columns for every list rather than recognizing them as lists of similar factors.

Here is a dput() of the start of the data (it is much larger):

```
dd = structure(list(id = c("rs62224609", "", "", "", "rs62224609", "",        "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "rs587626763", "", "", "", "rs62224609", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "rs62224609,rs587626763", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "rs587626763", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "rs587626763", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), library = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("42", "43", "44", "45_1", "45_2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"library"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")

head(dd, 8)
#           id library
# 1 rs62224609    45_1
# 2               45_1
# 3               45_1
# 4               45_2
# 5 rs62224609    45_2
# 6               45_2
# 7               45_1
# 8               45_1
```

Desired output

```
    rs62224609 
1            1
2            0
3            0
4            0
5            1
6            0
7            0
8            0
```

Comment: can you `dput()` your data?

Comment: I will edit my post.

Comment: The `dput` you shared is just a vector, not a data frame or a list. Can you please `dput` a subset of the data frame or list?

Comment: Sorry! I just sent a column of the data.  I have edited my post to reflect more of the dataset.  Let me know if there is anything else.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: so `col1` is a string in your first example?

Comment: Your `dput` data doesn't look at all like the example you show with output. Could you show the output you would want for the data you `dput()`? (Just the first 8 rows or so would be plenty)

Comment: @Gregor I had added a desired output.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: @mtoto is is a string.  I am trying to turn them all into factors - but each string contains many factors - so it model.matrix ends up just creating a unique factor for each string.

Comment: @Gregor and mtoto I've actually solved my question with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870523/converting-a-column-of-type-list-to-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame.  Thank you both for taking the time to look at the question!

Comment: Great, we should either close the question as a duplicate or you should post an answer. Let me know which you prefer.

Comment: We can close it as a duplicate.  How should I do that?